# bigint in mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I need to store twitter tweet ID numbers, and these numbers are big, like 16 digits big. I was wondering wheter to use bigint in mysql to store them? or is there another alternative. How many digits can bigint handle? I tried looking at the specs but it was not clear. What are the limitations of storing such big numbers in mysql table? thanks!

Comment: Might sound idiotic, but you don't have control over whether Twitter uses numbers for id or tomorrow is going to use strings. I'd go safety first if I don't have control over the datatype, and go string... But it's reaching a bit far I grant you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A bigint is 64bit, which goes -9223372036854775808 to 9223372036854775807 signed, and 0 to 18446744073709551615 unsigned, as per [the mysql docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/numeric-type-overview.html).

Answer (score 4):

Even if currently the IDs fit on a BIGINT (64bit signed), when the ID generation is outside your control, it's safer to store as a text string.

Not only it could grow even bigger (well, it's unlikely to ever overflow a BIGINT); but also you could later on add a prefix and store IDs from other systems in the same table.  Or maybe some future API could use non-numerical IDs

Comment: Unless you want to do any of the many things in mysql that are far faster using integers than strings...

Comment: ...which would actually be useful operations on IDs... such as?

Answer (score 2):

From the MySQL manual

> BIGINT[(M)] [UNSIGNED] [ZEROFILL]
>
> A large integer. The signed range is -9223372036854775808 to
>   9223372036854775807. The unsigned range is 0 to 18446744073709551615

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/numeric-type-overview.html

Comment: This is a definition of what a BIGINT type is, but it doesn't answer the question of what the OP should use and whether he should use BIGINT or not.

Answer (score 2):

I think, in regards to what [Wrikken](https://stackoverflow.com/users/358679/wrikken) [said](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6851825/bigint-in-mysql/10008960#comment8147876_6851825), it would be worth storing two IDs.

- string (VARCHAR) of the actual tweet ID so you have that (and just in case they do decide to go for characters as well).
- INT that you use for internal stuff such as linking tables

Answer (score 2):

You say you are using PHP.  You need to keep in mind that PHP's built-in numeric type is machine-dependant, and on x86 uses only 32 bits for integer values.  Values that are non-integer or are outside of the 32-bit range will be stored using float-point types, which are not designed to be accurate to the last digit for very large numbers.

While there are libraries for PHP that allow for portable big integers regardless of your architecture, it'd probably be easier just to keep the id field as a string the whole time.  Since you won't be doing any arithmetic on it, just treating it as an identifier, that shouldn't be a big problem.

Answer (score 1):

BigInt is the way to go. There is no more efficient datatype for this. BigInt can store nubers up to 2^64 which is about 25 Digits.